# Cross thread violation error inside Timer_Tick event

Tags: multithreading, c#-4.0, timer

My WinForm application invokes a thread to run a process, and also starts a WinForms Timer control Tick event at same time to display the progress of the thread process.

```
    public void threadTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblProgessCount.Text = countDownText;
    }
```

`countDownText` is a static string variable which is get updated from the thread process and time to time I want to display the latest value in it in a UI label control. But it gives me the below error,

> Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'lblProgressCount' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.

But the timer is started outside the thread process. Can anyone explain how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But the timer is started outside the thread process.

But you are manipulating the UI inside the timer callback. Here you are attempting to modify the UI from a different thread:

```
lblProgessCount.Text = ...
```

You should use the [`Invoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invoke.aspx) method to ensure that this action is marshaled to the main UI thread:

```
public void threadTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Action setValue = () => lblProgessCount.Text = countDownText;
    this.Invoke(setValue);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it worked. But also I want to show/hide some buttons within the same Tick event. How can I do that?

Comment: Like that: `Action setValue = () => { ... put as much code as you want here ... };`.